# In Google Analytics, how can I completely filter out visits that come to the homepage and then bounce to a subdomain?

Tags: google-analytics

The issue:  I want to filter out users who visit www.mysite.com then immediately go to app.mysite.com (there’s a link to “sign in” on the homepage.)

Here's the setup thus far:

```
    account: mysite.com

property: http://www.mysite.com
http://app.mysite.com

view:http://www.mysite.com

goal: The mysite.com view should not count users who visit www.mysite.com then immediately go to app.mysite.com (there’s a link to “sign in” on the homepage.)

I’ve applied the following filters:
1) filtername: exclude app
filter type: customer filter
exclude:filter field: hostname
filter pattern: app\.mysite\.com
Case sensitive: no

2) Remove App.mysite.com Bounces
filter type: predefined filter
exclude —> traffic to subdirectories —> that contain subdirectory: app.mysite.com
case sensitive: no
```

And yet, I'm still seeing all traffic, including the folks who come to the homepage in order to go to the app. Any help would be much, much appreciated--the forums haven't been much help thus far!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with view filters - they cannot filter pageviews in sequence, they only look at one request at a time. Plus you second filter will do nothing since a subdomain is not a subdirectory.

You cannot stop those visits from being tracked. However you can use segments in the report interface  to segment out the visits that you do not want to see (segments work on historical data, so they can take multiple pageviews into account).

There is a kind of segment that is called a sequence. You would create a segment that has NOT as a first user interaction in the visit a pageview at the homepage and as a second interaction NOT a pageview in the subdomain. There are already some good blog articles on how to use this (here is one by [Googles Justin Cuntroni](http://cutroni.com/blog/2013/07/16/google-analytics-segmentation/) - scroll to the middle of the post to find the part about sequences).

You then can apply  the segment to (most of) and they will show only your relevant data; the other visits will be still in the reports, but the segment will hide them.